# Cycles + holdout script has no effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

When I try to run this script inside blender with viewport set to cycles & rendering, this function does nothing.

How can I correct the issue?

```
def blockOutAll(hide=True):
    for a in bpy.data.collections:
        for item in a.objects:
            if item.type == "MESH":
                item.cycles.is_holdout = hide
```

Call `blockOutAll()`

TIA

Comment: It seems that setting the property by script doesn't trigger an update. It also doesn't change the state of the checkbox in *Object Properties > Visibility > Holdout* until you move the mouse over the panel.

Comment: Correct, is there a way to force update somehow?

Comment: shouldn't `is_holdout` be set to `True` instead of `hide`? EDIT: `hide=True` ahah, missed this

Comment: item.data.update() in the loop after setting "hide" seems to work